# PHP check if a string contains only 0-9 and a few other chars

Tags: php

I want to create a function where you check if a string contains only 0-9 /+*-{} (space) chars. This is similar to google's calculator query check.

```
function is_calculation($str) {
if (???) {return true;}
return false;
}
```

it needs to be something like /[0-9 *-/+ [] {} () ]/

Comment: I can write this code for you. I charge $50/hour with a minimum of two hours paid up-front. Do you have Paypal?

Comment: Did you think about regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (preg_match('/^[0-9\ \*\/\+\[\]\{\}\(\)\ -]+$/',$str)) {`

Comment: you're welcome, you practically had it, just needed to escape chars